# Monodromy representation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, galois-theory, fundamental-groups

In a scientific article on the net, i find without further details, the following paragraph :

Let $ X \subset \mathbb{C} $ be un open connected subset, and $ x \in X $.

A linear differential equation of order $ n $ : $$ y^{(n)} + a_1 y^{(n-1)} + \dots + a_{n-1} y' + a_n = 0 $$
 define a monodromy representation : $ \rho \ : \ \pi_1 (X,x) \to \mathrm{GL}_{n} ( \mathbb{C} ) $.

By the Cauchy existence theorem, the local solutions in a neighbourhood of $ x $ form a $ \mathbb{C} $ - vector space of dimension n endowed with monodromy action of $ \pi_1 (X,x) $.

- **My questions are to know** :

How is the monodromy representation $ \rho \ : \ \pi_1 (X,x) \to \mathrm{GL}_{n} ( \mathbb{C} ) $ defined, and, what is the intuition and the use of $ \rho $ compared to the linear differential equation : $ y^{(n)} + a_1 y^{(n-1)} + \dots + a_{n-1} y' + a_n = 0 $ ?

**N.B.** : The paragraph above is from the following pdf : http://www.galois.ihp.fr/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/T.-Szamuely.pdf , page : $ 48 $.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127108/how-to-compute-the-monodromy-group-for-a-given-differential-equation/

Comment: Note that $a_1,..,a_{n-1}$ are not constants, but functions defined on $X$. Try working out some examples, like the one at mercio's link, or even easier : $y'-\frac{1}{2z}y=0$ on $X=\mathbb{C}^*$. Can you define a global solution ?

Comment: You might also have a look here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147268/example-of-a-local-system/2147504#2147504

Comment: Thank you Roland and mercio for your help. @Roland : Sorry, i don't know to solve this kind of équation in $ \mathbb{C} $. I've never done this before , sorry. Any help ?  :-)

Comment: I wrote the details in the thread linked in my previous comment (see the example at (iii) ). Have a look and tell me if there is specific point you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you very much Roland. I understand now how all those things work.  :-) Thank you again. :-)

Comment: Take a look at E.Hille, "Ordinary Differential Equations in the Complex Domain".